# Slave Miner Killed By Seemingly Nothing

Tags: command-and-conquer-yuris-revenge

I was playing Red Alert 2: Yuri's Revenge, recently, and I experienced something strange. My slave miner was killed, and I'm not really sure how it happened. The other slaves were considered neutral and gray.

The only teams were green and me, on red, versus light blue and pink. The AI was set to medium difficulty.

[image: Example screenshot.]

After playing Yuri's Revenge for years, I have never seen anything weirder than this. What could have happened to kill my slave miner?

Comment: what teams were you playing against?

Comment: Teams A(Me and Green), and B (Light Blue, Pink)

Comment: Are you playing the disk version, or the Origin version? If it's the Origin version, you might have been hit by RA2's anti-piracy measure (which automatically kills all units 30 seconds after the game started).

Comment: Disk version, and if it kills all units why didn't it kill my tanks below the slaves?

Comment: @Someperson99 which country was each team?

Comment: Red(me): Yuri Green:America Light-Blue:France Pink:Great Britain

Comment: British snipers will do something like this. Longest range infantry in the game.

Comment: I've never heard of a Sniper killing a Slave miner before, do you know how many shots it would take to kill that thing.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that could kill your slave miner and make the slaves neutral is one of your own slaves, as you can see the one that destroyed it had received a promotion as well. So I would say that slave somehow got stuck maybe and started beating it with its shovel till it got destroyed. Other players can not do it since than the slaves color would be the one that destroyed the miner, if a neutral entity e.g. an animal would attack it than the miner would kill it with ease.

So yeah it was your own slave.